# How to handle requests.exception.ConnectionError in multiprocessing python

Tags: python, exception, multiprocessing, python-requests

I've read many articles before posting my question because none of them answer to it or it was too complicated for my knowledge in Python.
I'm trying to send several post requests with multiprocessing and I notice that when my Raspberry Pi didn't succeed to connect to the network I had some 
`ConnectionError: ('Connection Aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')`

So I'm doing this in my code :

```
url = "https://some_url.org}"
list.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=requests.post, args=(url,)))

#doing this several times with several urls, then

for element in list:
    element.start()
for element in list:
    element.join()
```

I know that I have to do `from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError`, I've tried a simple `try:` `except:` in the ̀`for` loop but it's not working because the exception is located in the child process. 
Here is the traceback :

```
Process Process-6:
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 94, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 94, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: How to handle requests.exception.ConnectionError in multiprocessing

Use a `wrapper` for the `requests.post(url)` call, for instance:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import requests

def req_wrapper(url):
    try:
        requests.post(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception catched in req_wrapper:{}'.format(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://some_url.org"
    p = mp.Process(target=req_wrapper, args=(url,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

> **Output**:
>   Exception catched in req_wrapper:('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 and 2.7.9***

Comment: Yes I've already try this and it doesn't work, it seems that I've to make communicate my parent process with the child process created by the multiprocessing method

Comment: @GarennePb: Updated my Answer